# Getting "InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character" for an option in list box

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following line in my jsp file:

```
var option = document.createElement('<option value="NO">');
```

Not sure why this gives me `InvalidCharacterError`.

Any alternatives?

Comment: I think you were missed `'<select>'` element. first create `<select>` and after that add this `'<option value="NO">'`.

Comment: The full error is `InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('<option value="NO">') is not a valid name.` You need to include it in a `select` element

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to add  to your  tag.

```
var myoption = document.createElement("option");
myoption.setAttribute("value", "carvalue");
var text = document.createTextNode("maruti");
myoption.appendChild(text);
document.getElementById("mySelect").appendChild(myoption);
```

Answer (score 4):

There was a change in DOM implementation.
Before, you could create a new element with the code inside, for instance:

**BAD**

```
var anElement = document.createElement("<A HREF=\"http://stackoverflow.com \">StackOverflow</A>")
```

This implementation now, returns this ‘InvalidCharacterError’.
What you must do now is to create the element and to populate it using the innerHTML attribute or the different specific attributes for any node.

**GOOD**

```
var anElement = document.createElement("a")
anElement.innerHTML = ("<A HREF=\"http://stackoverflow.com \">StackOverflow</A>")
```